# Tablesorter - Update Filter header DropDown after Appending Table Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a tablesorter table that looks like below.

[image]

As you can see, the "License" Filter, has 2 entries.

If I dynamically add a row so that the table looks like below.
[image]

I have tried updating the table using

`$('#connectionGrid2').trigger('updateAll', [false]);`
`$('#connectionGrid2').trigger('updateCache', [false]);`
`$('#connectionGrid2').trigger('update', [false]);`

Yet these updates do not get the new value to appear in the dropdown.

Is it possible to update the filter header dropdown without reinitallizing the tablesorter?

Comment: No, it just isn't adding the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check to make sure you're using the most up-to-date version.

Otherwise, everything appears to be working as expected in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/913/)

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['filter']
    });
  $('button').click(function(){
      var row = [
        '<tr>',
          '<td>Lisa</td>',
          '<td>Chemistry</td>',
          '<td>Female</td>',
          '<td>99</td>',
          '<td>99</td>',
          '<td>99</td>',
          '<td>99</td>',
        '</tr>'
      ].join('');
      $('tbody')
        .append($(row))
        .trigger('update');
  });
});
```

If you are still having issues, please modify that demo to duplicate the problem to make troubleshooting it easier. Thanks!

Comment: This appears to work, but is there anyway to trigger the update after adding rows? I am adding rows in a loop, and this style would call `trigger('update')` for each row, when I figured I would just `update` after adding all X number rows

Comment: It seems that both the `$(ele).append(row).trigger('update')` as well as a post loop `updateCache` were needed

Comment: You could also use the [`addRows` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#addrows), it will only add the rows passed to it into the cache and not update everything.